# How to solve equation with variable in integral

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

Here is the equation I want to solve. [$c$ and $M$ have specified values, and I want the value of $p$.]:

$$(2p-c)\int_p^M\frac1{n^2}e^{p-n}\,\mathrm dn=1-\frac{c}{p}$$

For example with $c=0.1$ and $M=10$, I can plot the function in *Mathematica* and see that the solution is about 0.735. If I write the code

```
c=1

M=50

NSolve[(2 p - c)*
NIntegrate[(1/n^2)*Exp[p - n], {n, p, M}] - (1 - c/p) == 0, {p, 0.75}]
```

When I run the code in *Mathematica* I get

```
nlim: "n = p is not a valid limit of integration.
```

I get it. `p` is in the limit of integration. But if I go from `NIntegrate` to regular `Integrate`, then after a few minutes I get

```
This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve. >>


NSolve[ConditionalExpression[-1 + 1/
p + (-1 + 2 p) (-(1/50) E^(-50 + p) + 1/p - 
   E^p ExpIntegralEi[-50] + E^p ExpIntegralEi[-p]) == 0, 0 < Re[p] < 50 && Im[p] == 0], p]
```

I appreciate that the function I'm using is connected to the Exponential Integral (or Upper Incomplete Gamma Function). That's why I need *Mathematica*'s help. Here a graph shows that the solution is about 1.75.

Ultimately, I'm looking to get $p(c, M)$ -- $p$ as a function of $c$ and $M$. Actually, I'd be happy with graphing $p$ as a function of $c$ and $M$.

Note also that with some other values of $c$ and $M$, I get a solution using `Integrate` but there is a different error. For example, with $c=0.1$, $M=10$ I get

```
Warning: NSolve was unable to prove that the solution set found is complete. >>

{{p -> 0.735228}}
```

Any guidance for how I can find a numerical solution for $p(c,M)$?

Comment: `NSolve[]` is not really intended for use with transcendental equations like yours. Use `FindRoot[]`, but make sure you have a good starting guess.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: J.M is a god. Thank you!

Comment: Barry Nalebuff here? I've heard about you here in Brazil.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with a plot from 0 to 100, one can narrow down the root:

```
Block[{c = 1, M = 50},
 NSolve[(2 p - c)*
      Integrate[(1/n^2)*Exp[p - n], {n, p, M}, 
       Assumptions -> 0 < p] - (1 - c/p) == 0 && 0 < p < 5, p]
 ]
(*  {{p -> 1.75081}}  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I do:

```
i[p_, M_] := NIntegrate[(1/x^2)*Exp[p - x], {x, p, M}]
f[y_, c_] := (2 y - c)*i[y, 50] - (1 - 1/y)
Plot[f[y, 1], {y, 0, 1}]
```

I get a nice plot.

```
FindRoot[{f[y, 1] == 0}, {y, 0.75}]
```

complains like you describe, but eventually gives

```
 {y->1.7508107}
```

I'm not sure why there are the complaints about "x = y is not a valid limit of integration" ...

Answer (score 2):

With J.M's help the FindRoot did the trick. Note that if one integrates by parts the result is the same as the ExpIntegralEi function. And now the solution is instantaneous:

```
FindRoot[Exp[-t]/(-ExpIntegralEi[-t] + ExpIntegralEi[-M]) == 2 t - c, {t, c + 1}]
```

Comment: FWIW: `-ExpIntegralEi[-t]` is the same as `ExpIntegralE[1, t]`.

Answer (score 2):

> Actually, I'd be happy with graphing $p$ as a function of $c$ and $M$.

In that case, you can just use `ContourPlot3D[]` to generate your desired plot.

```
ContourPlot3D[(2 p - c) Exp[p] Gamma[-1, p, M] == 1 - c/p,
              {c, 0, 30}, {M, 0, 30}, {p, 0, 40}]
```

[image: plot of implicit surface]

(Note that I have taken the opportunity to use the three-argument form of the incomplete gamma function, which *Mathematica* has support for.)